# Auto login after Wake On Lan

Tags: python, windows, authentication, automation, wake-on-lan

I have got the Wake On Lan feature working. But after I start the computers they get stuck at the windows login screen obviously as the computers have passwords.

Is there any way to auto login after Wake On Lan or somehow automate the login process without removing the password. I found threads discussing a possibility that you could run a script as a service or something, but couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on SuperUser. WoL packets can't specify how to login (OS independent, controlled by your NIC). You may want to always do an auto-login when it turns on (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows ) or perhaps once it is started, use remote desktop software to log in the remote computer from your own. Tell me, if this comment is better to be an answer?

Comment: @El8tedN8te Ok I will try to ask  there. The thing is that I would like to have a password but auto login only on when the computer is turned on by Wake On Lan. Remote desktop software could be solution but I have tens of computers so automating that would be quite hard

Comment: incase if you use windows, theres a system tool called task scheduler that can do automate various stuffs without logging in (trigger at startup, and in general option tick Run whether user logged in or not) (EDIT: ops you already found the same answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this with Python and Windows Task Scheduler. With Task scheduler you can run tasks based on events like startup. I created a Python script that changes the password to a blank one and restarts the computer, this way it doesn't require the password for login. In Task Scheduler you have to check the **run with highest privileges** and **run whether the user is logged in or not**. Then I created another script that after log in event changes the password back to what it was.

In my opinion this is some kind of security flaw but more experienced people can give their opinion about that.

Comment: Does this method still work? If so, can you post the python script for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TeamViewer to enter the machine already during the login process. Then you can fill out the password manually through that (and also access the machine thereafter).

As far as I am aware if you install TeamViewer machine-wide (i.e. not for one user) this works out of the box.